# How to modify the API call while building API interface in compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build an API interface to access the following

`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/HNCSCpWrVJA?client_id=//...//`

My API interface looks like this in jetpack compose

```
@Singleton
interface PhotoViewApi {
    @GET(value = "photos")
    suspend fun searchPhotos(
        @Query("client_id")client_id:String
    ): searchPhotos
}
```

Since I am just learning, I really don't know how to manipulate the photo id "HNCSCpWrVJA"
from the API interface, I know that query parameters can be manipulated with `@Query` annotation that is client_id what comes after `?` in API call link, in this case,
but how would I be able to dynamically change photo id?

`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/<---PHOTO_ID--->?client_id=//...//`

from interface

Answer (score 0):

```
@Singleton
interface PhotoViewApi {

    @GET(value = "photos/{photo_id}")
    suspend fun searchPhotos(
        @Query("client_id")client_id:String,
        @Path("photo_id") photoId:String
    ): searchPhotos

}
```

You can use `@Path` to pass photo id in your url